# Jquery not returning basic string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```js
$(".1").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "blue") {
    console.log("there");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1">
    blue 
</button>
<button class="1">
    1
</button>

<button class="1">
    Booked 
</button>
```

Doesn't log anything, but instead of blue if i put 1, it logs it. 
therefore, its not detecting string, previously, innerHTML also behaves the same way, when we compare it to an exact string value like, 
`$(this).text() == "apple"`, it will never display anything.

Comment: RRK removing spaces will make a big difference in OP original HTML and will affect especially that the problem with OP is white space

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the text before comparing.

```js
$(".1").each(function() {
  if($.trim($(this).text()) == "blue") {
    console.log("there");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1">
blue 
</button>

<button class="1">
1
</button>

<button class="1">
Booked 
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `.trim()` to compare there might be extra white space

```js
$(".1").each(function() {
if($(this).text().trim() == 'blue'){
  console.log($(this).text());
}
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1">
    blue 
    </button>

<button class="1">
    1
    </button>

<button class="1">
    Booked 
    </button>
```